# App is crashed at Google maps part

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, maps, jelly

I have placed this code in the onCreate class.

```
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    String uri = "geo:" + latitude + "," + longitude;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
    this.startActivity(intent);
```

When the app is opening, ill get Unfortunaley, App is stopped.
In logcat ill get the error:

```
01-17 05:42:08.734: D/AndroidRuntime(1659): Shutting down VM
01-17 05:42:08.734: W/dalvikvm(1659): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
01-17 05:42:08.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1659): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 05:42:08.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1659): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.farugh.neshaniha/com.solidos.neshaniha.FullscreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 05:42:08.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
01-17 05:42:08.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
01-17 05:42:08.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-17 05:42:08.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
01-17 05:42:08.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-17 05:42:08.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 05:42:08.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-17 05:42:08.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 05:42:08.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-17 05:42:08.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-17 05:42:08.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-17 05:42:08.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-17 05:42:08.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1659): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 05:42:08.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at com.solidos.neshaniha.FullscreenActivity.onCreate(FullscreenActivity.java:36)
01-17 05:42:08.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
01-17 05:42:08.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-17 05:42:08.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
01-17 05:42:08.744: E/AndroidRuntime(1659):     ... 11 more
```

How is this possible?

Kind Regards,
Marvin

Comment: Post the logcat, don't summarize it for us

Comment: NullPointerException at `FullscreenActivity.java:35`. Which line is it?

Comment: double longitude = location.getLongitude();
This one.

Comment: If the provider is disabled (or the device has never before requested a location), getLastKnownLocation() will return null. Are you using the emulator or real device?

Comment: At devices the app is stopping and in the emulator.

Comment: have you set the GPS and location permissions in your manifest?

Comment: I have ACCES_COARSE_LOCATION, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS,ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION for GPS.

Comment: Just to be sure, are you using Google Maps v2 so you have Google Play Services library in your project? Thanks.

Comment: android.permission.INTERNET is in the manifest.
Ill only have an meta-data with the com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY

Comment: Google Play Services installed and tryed to run.. Same problem. App has stopped.

Comment: Nobody that can help me?

Comment: put if(location!=null) before using it, so maybe the problem is that you actually don't get any location.